# strTok function (thread safe, supports empty tokens, doesn't change string)

Tags: beginner, c, strings

I'm new to C language and want to explode a string like we do in PHP `explode()` function, I searched for a built-in function with the C standard library, and I found `strtok` , but It doesn't support empty tokens like `1,2,3,,5` . Inspired by the answers I found in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3375776/5407848) I made this function, it is supposed to be thread safe and support empty tokens and doesn't change the original string

```
char* strTok(char** newString, char* delimiter)
{
    char* string = *newString;
    char* delimiterFound = (char*) 0;
    int tokLenght = 0;
    char* tok = (char*) 0;

    if(!string) return (char*) 0;

    delimiterFound = strstr(string, delimiter);

    if(delimiterFound){
        tokLenght = delimiterFound-string;
    }else{
        tokLenght = strlen(string);
    }

    tok = malloc(tokLenght + 1);
    memcpy(tok, string, tokLenght);
    tok[tokLenght] = '\0';

    *newString = delimiterFound ? delimiterFound + strlen(delimiter) : (char*)0;

    return tok;
}
```

I designed it to be used like

```
char* input = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,,10,";
char** inputP = &input;
char* tok;
while( (tok=strTok(inputP, ",")) ){
    printf("%s\n", tok);
}
```

Comment: Better user-interface then the original `strtok`. You may be interested in `strsep`, too. https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strsep.c.html

Comment: @NeilEdelman thanks I never saw this function before, I will check it.

Comment: It's not in the standard `C` libraries, but in `POSIX`, (any type of `gcc`.) However, like `strtok`, it obliterates the `char` to replace it with `\0`, so it's not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `delimiterFound + strlen(delimiter)` sounds like a bug. If the delimiter is longer than one character, `*newString` will point too far into the original, maybe even beyond the end. Correct me if I am wrong, `delimiterFound + 1` is what you are actually after.
- Modern C allows, and strongly encourages, to declare variables as close to their use a possible. Consider

  ```
  char * delimiterFound = strstr(string, delimiter);
  ....
  char * tok = malloc(tokLenght + 1);
  ```

  etc.
- Always test that `malloc` didn't fail.
- More spaces - around keywords, braces, etc - definitely improve readability:

  ```
      if (....) {
          ....
      } else {
          ....
      }
  ```

Comment: Thaaank you very much for these precious points, regarding the delimiter length bug, ummmm, I want to support long delimiters more than 1 characters like the boundary string in http requests that has content-type multi-part, and I don't think it's a bug because `delimiterFound + strlen(delimiter)` can never be after the 0 byte that terminates the original string!, right ? `"fooDELIMITER"   3 + 12`

Comment: @Accountantم Long delimiters here refer to, say `",;."`, in where any character delimits the string on its own right.

Comment: I didn't get it, I'm sorry, can you please give me an example input that can break this code, exploiting this bug ?

Comment: @Accountantم Sorry for not being clear. I should realize that your intentions are different (and read `man strstr` more carefully). Consider it my blinder - since you mentioned `strtok`, I expected the `strtok` semantics.

Comment: It's my fault because I said it's `strtok`, I wanted `strtok` that can support delimiters more than 1 characters, because I need this feature a lot. So do you mean it's not a bug ??

Comment: *"Long delimiters here refer to, say ",;.", in where any character delimits the string on its own right."*... aha, now I get it, no no, what I wanted is one delimiter with 1 or more characters e.g `"fooDELIMITERbar"`

Answer (score 2):

From a readability viewpoint, you should use `NULL` instead of `(char*) 0` as it is easier to recognize what you're trying to do.  Also, the `tokLenght` misspells "length", and should probably be `tokLength`.

You leak memory, as the memory allocated to hold the returned string is never freed.

Comment: Thank you very much I will use NULL from now on, and I will remember to `free()` memory , *'I miss PHP garbage collector :('*,  I didn't get the `tokLength` spelling note, aren't they the same ?

Comment: It's a matter of style, and including `.h` if you want to use `NULL`. However, you don't have to cast `(char *)0`, just use `0` (or `NULL`.) It knows from the return type.

Comment: @Accountantم For the spelling, you used G-H-T when the correct spelling is G-T-H (the last two letters are swapped).  I've made that typo before.  I find having identifiers spelled correctly helps with reading and finding them, although the autocomplete in IDEs mitigates that a little but propagates the misspellings.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm ooh,  how come I didn't notice this after revising it multiple times!, thanks.